# World camera: impossible to change its initial position in Gazebo with ROS Fuerte

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to Gazebo. I'm using Gazebo 1.0.2 with ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

I am trying to change the initial world camera position in Gazebo but I'm facing the same issue described in this topic :

http://answers.ros.org/question/39862/gazebo-initial-view-of-world-my-renderinggui-fltk-tag-is-not-working/

When I'm launching Gazebo using the command :

$ roslaunch gazebo_test1 test1.launch

I noticed the Warnings :

*Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element*

*namespace error : Namespace prefix rendering on gui is not defined '<'rendering:gui'>'*

*namespace error : Namespace prefix rendering on ogre is not defined '<'rendering:ogre'>'*

*Warning [parser.cc:245] DEPRECATED GAZEBO WORLD FILE On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported Convert your files using the gzsdf command line tool You have been warned!*

These warnings can explain my issue.
It seems that my syntax is quite old but it's the same syntax that the one provided with gazebo examples in ROS.

Do you know where I can find the latest syntax or How I could solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/106/world-camera:-impossible-to-change-its-initial-position-in-gazebo-with-ros-fuerte/) by [ad34](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/63/ad34/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 1.0.x uses SDF 1.0, which is documented http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.0.html.

Looks like you need to add a `<gui>` tag as a child to your `<world>` tag, e.g.:

```
<world>
...
  <gui>
    <camera>
      <origin pose="0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
    </camera>
  </gui>
</world>
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-11**:
This functionality is not working in Gazebo 1.3, but it working in the default branch and in the upcoming 1.4 release.